# convert multidimensional array to single array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

hi  i have array like:-

```
Array
  (
[0] => Array
    (
        [payment_id] => 3160
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [action] => update
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2017-05-17 09:59:40
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [payment_date] => 23.05.2017
    )
   )
```

i want to remove the key 0,1, 2
i want my array to be like this

```
 Array
 (
[payment_id] => 3160
 [action] => update
   [date] => 2017-05-17 09:59:40
    [payment_date] => 23.05.2017
)
```

how can i get this using php

Answer (score 2):

check `array_reduce ()` built in function

```
<?php
$your_array = array(0 => array('payment_id' => 3160), 1 => array('action' => 'update'), 2 => array('date' => '2017-05-17 09:59:40'), 3 => array('payment_date' => '23.05.201'));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($your_array);
$convert_array = array_reduce($your_array, 'array_merge', array());
echo "<pre>";
print_r($convert_array);
```

then output is :

Original Array :

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [payment_id] => 3160
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [action] => update
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-05-17 09:59:40
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [payment_date] => 23.05.201
        )

)
```

Output :

```
 Array
(
    [payment_id] => 3160
    [action] => update
    [date] => 2017-05-17 09:59:40
    [payment_date] => 23.05.201
)
```

for more help

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $v)
{
  $result[key($v)] = current($v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) along with [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) function:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)); 
$result = iterator_to_array($iterator,true);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fe04ef6c1f155ebac8cde7044af886b076315e3).